# Open a portrait page from Pivot Page Listbox with "LineThree" text in it

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

As the title says...
If I start my app project with a pivot page(MainPage.xaml) and then choose to click for example the "design two" link in the databinded listbox. Is it possible to bind the "LineThree" text for the "design two" link in to a separate portrait page?

Do I have to make new portrait page for every "LineThree"-link? Or can I just generate the "MainViewModelSampleData.xaml" data to a single portrait page depending on what "LineOne"-link I click in the pivot page in the start?

Hope my question is understandable... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a main page that contains a list of data, and then a details page whose contents are dependent on the item that you clicked in the main page. The answer to your question is then "yes". There are a number of ways to achieve this, some of which include global variables, a custom navigation service, storing a value in isolated storage and so on. My personal preference is to use the context of the `NavigationService` and to pass an ID or an index in the query string for the target page.

Your call to navigate to the details page then looks like this:

```
Application.Current.Navigate(string.Format("/Views/DetailsView.xaml?id={0}", id));
```

In the target page, you override the `OnNavigatedTo` handler to retrieve the value that you passed and then process it accordingly (i.e. look up the value from your database, or retrieve it from a data collection).

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("id"))
    {
        var id = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];
        // TODO: Do what you need to with the ID.
    }
    else
    {
        // I use this condition to handle creating new items.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a good answer! Haven´t studied for a while and totally forgot about item id:s. :P

Answer (score 0):

How is what you're trying to do different from what is created by default in a new DataBound Application? That lets you select an item in the list on the main page and then displays another page which includes the text from LineThree.

I suggest you look at the sample code created as part of a new DataBound Application.